# Cannot assign null value to variable

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm confused at the various errors in my class so far.

I'm creating a service that returns some data (it will come from a db soon so have set it up as observable).

[image]

First error is that @Injectable is having some issues

[image]

Second error is that i can't assign null to a variable?

[image]

I tried to take this from the angular tutorial here: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "SpaceGame.WebUI",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "karma start ClientApp/test/karma.conf.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/common": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/core": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/forms": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/http": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-server": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/router": "4.2.5",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "1.5.0",
    "@types/chai": "4.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.53",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.0",
    "angular2-router-loader": "0.3.5",
    "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.1",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "chai": "4.0.2",
    "css": "2.2.1",
    "css-loader": "0.28.4",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.3",
    "event-source-polyfill": "0.0.9",
    "expose-loader": "0.7.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.2",
    "file-loader": "0.11.2",
    "html-loader": "0.4.5",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.6.4",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "json-loader": "0.5.4",
    "karma": "1.7.0",
    "karma-chai": "0.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-webpack": "2.0.3",
    "preboot": "4.5.2",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "5.4.2",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
    "typescript": "2.4.1",
    "url-loader": "0.5.9",
    "webpack": "2.5.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.18.2",
    "webpack-merge": "4.1.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.12"
  }
}
```

Comment: What are the version numbers of the `@angular` packages that are listed in your *package.json* for the application? What version of rxjs are you using, too?

Comment: I've added to the question. Thanks man

Comment: That explains the issue. You are trying to use features, like `providedIn`, which are only available starting in Angular 6. Same with rxjs 6 and the location of... `of`. Consider upgrading to the latest versions, or following a tutorial for an older version of Angular.

Comment: Ahhh. thanks dude! I'll see if i can just upgrade angular.

Comment: Excellent choice! Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, i installed the new angular (what a pain in the neck it always is.. whatever happened to one button clicks :'( ) - I still have the problem with the assigning null to a local variable :) - Thanks for the other help though!

Comment: Consider not assigning the variable equal to `null`. It will be undefined by default. Maybe... work with that. And yes! the update to ng 6 can be a pain!!! v 4 to 6, not a huge jump, but enough to make the trip more than a little unpleasant in some cases. (worth it though, I hope) To the bleeding edge!!!